# Update data from linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm making some linked list for a project. I have already coded an add in list

```
t_team *add_team(t_team *teams, char *team_name, int id)
{
  t_team *tmp;

  if ((tmp = malloc(sizeof(t_team))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);

  if ((tmp->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(team_name) + 1)) == NULL)
    return (NULL);

  strcpy(tmp->name, team_name);
  tmp->id = id;
  tmp->next = teams;
  return (tmp);
}
```

But i need to update the Id of one particular node of the list, how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Update your post to include an [mcve]

Comment: Search for the node to be updated. Update it.  Not very hard. What is the problem, other than you haven't yet written a search function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Find the list you want to update

```
t_team *find_by_name(t_team *head, char *team_name)
{
  t_team * tmp = head;
  while(tmp != NULL){
    if(strcmp(tmp->name, team_name) != 0)
      head = tmp->next; //Advance the pointer to next element
    else
      return tmp;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Step 2: Update the filed
Call this utility from  your primary function:-

```
  t_team *tmp = find_by_name(head, "Some_Name");
  if( tmp == NULL)
    //element not found
  else
     tmp->id = new_id; //Update ID
```

Update:- Updated *find_by_name* to use a tmp instead of modifying head

Comment: I updated using a tmp - The snippet was to give OP an idea what needs to be done